# Java How to decrypt a byte array given the method

Tags: java, encryption

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class EncryptDecryptExample
{
    // "thisIsASecretKey";
    private static byte[] key = { 0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65,
            0x79 };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //********************WORKS**********************
        String x = "Hello";
        System.out.println("Plain Text: " + x);
        String e = EncryptString(x);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + e);
        String d = decryptString(e);
        System.out.println("Deccypted: " + d);

        //********************WORKS**********************
        Byte b = 124;
        System.out.println("Plain Byte: "+b.toString());
        String eb = EncryptString(b.toString());
        System.out.println("Encrypted Byte: "+eb);
        String bd = decryptString(eb);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Byte: "+bd);

        //********************DOESNT*WORK*********************
        Byte[] bArray = {23, 42, 55};
        System.out.println("Plain Byte Array: "+bArray[0].toString()+","+bArray[1].toString()+","+bArray[2].toString());
        String eba = EncryptString(bArray.toString());
        System.out.println("Encrypted Byte Array: "+eba.toString());
        String deba = decryptString(eba.toString());
        System.out.println("Decrypted Byte Array: "+deba.getBytes()[0]);  //<--- Doesn't work
        //*********************************************
    }

    public static String EncryptString(String strToEncrypt) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public static String decryptString(String strToDecrypt) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)));
        return decryptedString;
    }

}
```

**Result:**

> ```
> Plain Text: Hello
> Encrypted: VKzhMlqHstjsGJHhbFS5wA==
> Deccypted: Hello
> Plain Byte: 124
> Encrypted Byte: fuRAfj1yLXnEp+g25a1iYg==
> Decrypted Byte: 124
> Plain Byte Array: 23,42,55
> Encrypted Byte Array: lURk/e+MIt6xa9s3wBnmKxyiuOmM/6JfwX6ujttNqWw=
> Decrypted Byte Array: 91 <--- ?? why is this wrong
> ```

**Why cant I retrieve my bytes back from the byte array correctly?**

---->NOTE

**I would like one, all mighty decrypt and one encrypt method. I'm aware I can do this with different method signatures. But I don't want an overloaded function.**

Comment: You are encrypting the `toString()` representation of a `byte[]`, see `String eba = EncryptString(bArray.toString());`

Comment: What is the value you get as your bArray.toString()?

Comment: @blo0p3r it is: [Ljava.lang.Byte;@74b2002f

Comment: my first comment shows your first mistake, the other is how you try to read bytes from a string. Just try what `"5".getBytes()[0];` will be :) Have an ASCII Table at your hand ;)

Comment: That above is the address representation of the byte array, not it's content.

Comment: Are you looking to convert the Array in a whole or content of the array?  You could convert every entry one by one, have that stored in an array, and then on decription do the same thing?  As @Henrik pointed out in an answer there are issues with Arrays.

Comment: @blo0p3r see the edited question at the very bottom. I'm aware byte arrays can be decrypted but I want to manipulate each type to fit into my defined functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to get the desired result by changing the last block:

```
...
    //*********************************************
    byte[] bArray = {23, 42, 55};
    String stringRepresentation = bArray[0] + "," + bArray[1] + "," + bArray[2];
    System.out.println("Plain Byte Array: " + Arrays.toString(bArray));
    String eba = EncryptByteArray(bArray);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Byte Array: "+eba);
    byte[] deba = decryptByteArray(eba);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Byte Array: "+Arrays.toString(deba));
    //*********************************************
}

public static String EncryptByteArray(byte[] array) throws Exception
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(array));
    return encryptedString;
}

public static byte[] decryptByteArray(String strToDecrypt) throws Exception
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and it does work as desired but my goal was to manipulate each data type to work with the existing function. I will up vote your response regardless

Comment: @Mrshll187, I have previously provided decision which uses only `EncryptString` and `decryptString`, but somebody deducted it and I have to delete it.

Comment: @Mrshll187, also you could rewrite your `EncryptString` and `decryptString` so that they will simply invoke `EncryptByteArray` and `decryptByteArray` passing them `.getBytes()`/retrieving `new String(...)`

Comment: well thats a crock of crap. I would have been interested in seeing that response

Comment: I'm getting the consensus that your probably right with your last response

Comment: Sorry for delay, I was in the road. I glad that my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: can u write the libs?

Answer (score 2):

To `toString` method of an array does not give you the contents of the array as a String. It merely provides you with a rather obscure reference identifier.

Your problem is in the following line:

```
Byte[] bArray = {23, 42,   
String eba = EncryptString(bArray.toString());
```

Consider using the [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29) method to turn the byte array into an encryptable string.

```
String eba = EncryptString(Arrays.toString(bArray));
```

**Update:**
As @jlordo points out below, variations of the same error are present in the lines below, i.e.

```
System.out.println("Encrypted Byte Array: "+eba.toString());
String deba = decryptString(eba.toString());
```

Comment: But you have to recreate the `byte[]` after decrypting, you can't use `getBytes()`. That's what he is doing.

Comment: Good point. Several errors then. All of them seem to originate in a misunderstanding of how arrays are converted to and from strings.

Comment: Since the cryptographic functions work on byte arrays, it is of course pretty stupid to format the byte array as a comma separated list in a string, encode this string with some sort of character encoding to a byte array and then encrypt that array instead of encrypting the byte array directly.

Comment: @Henrik so do I need to go to each index; encrypt and decrypt in that fashion?

Comment: @jarnbjo its not encoded in common delimited. Its merely printing it out that way for the observer

Comment: @jarnbjo: A valid point, but it is nevertheless the source of the error. I think it makes some sense in the context where only {en|de}cryptString methods exist.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using byte[] as the input and output of your crypt functions.  You do not need to overload.  Crypt functions that work with byte[] will be able to store and retrieve any data type.

As far as I know, there is no simple inverse of Arrays.toString(byte[]).  If there were an inverse, you could proceed with your program without many modifications.  But, there isn't.

You would want something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
String stringRepresentationOfBytes = Arrays.toString(bytes);
byte[] stringRepresentationOfBytesConvertedBackToByteArray = 
    ByteArray.fromString(stringRepresentationOfBytes);
```

But there's no such thing as `ByteArray.fromString(String)`.

I suggest using byte[] as your basic datatype going into and out of your crypt functions:

```
public class SOEncryptDecryptExampleBytes
{
    // "thisIsASecretKey";
    private static byte[] key = { 0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79 };

    private static final String STRING_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //*********************************************
        String x = "Hello";
        System.out.println("Plain Text: " + x);
        String e = encryptBytesAndBase64Encode(x.getBytes(STRING_ENCODING));
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + e);
        byte[] d = base64decodeAndDecryptBytes(e);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + new String(d, STRING_ENCODING));

        //*********************************************
        byte b = 124;
        System.out.println("Plain Byte: " + b);
        String eb = encryptBytesAndBase64Encode(new byte[] { b });
        System.out.println("Encrypted Byte: " + eb);
        byte[] bd = base64decodeAndDecryptBytes(eb);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Byte: " + bd[0]);

        //*********************************************
        byte[] bArray = { 23, 42, 55 };
        System.out.println("Plain Byte Array: " + Arrays.toString(bArray));
        String eba = encryptBytesAndBase64Encode(bArray);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Byte Array: " + eba);
        byte[] deba = base64decodeAndDecryptBytes(eba);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Byte Array: " + Arrays.toString(deba));
        //*********************************************
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a byte[] into an encrypted byte[] and then uses base64 encodes the encrypted byte[]
     */
    public static String encryptBytesAndBase64Encode(byte[] bytes) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
        return encryptedString;
    }

    /**
     * Base64 decodes a string into a byte[] and then decrypts those bytes into a decrypted byte[]
     */
    public static byte[] base64decodeAndDecryptBytes(String base64EncodedEncryptedBytes) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedEncryptedBytes));
        return decryptedBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mrshll187 By the way, if you want your encrypted strings to work when transmitted across different systems (e.g. win->mac->linux, or computer_in_france->computer_in_russia), you should use a consistent encoding parameter when converting a string to and from bytes.  See the parts of my example program that mention the constant "STRING_ENCODING".  If you don't specify this parameter, Java just uses whatever the OS's current default character encoding is, and that can vary based on locale and OS.